# How to add watermark to video with ffmpeg after 1 minute, lasting 30 seconds?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, watermark

I would like to watermark videos using ffmpeg, with the watermark showing after 60 seconds, with the watermark showing for only 30 seconds, then disappearing for the rest of the video. Can anyone share the command for this?

I'm using Windows by the way

Answer (score 0):

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i movie -loop 1 -i watermark \
       -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x:y:enable='between(t,60,90)'" \
       output.mp4
```

Comment: Does this command work for Windows? I tried this and it didn't work for me

Comment: What command did you use?

Comment: I used `ffmpeg -i inputvideo.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex \ "[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10:enable=between(t\,0\,30)" -codec:a copy outputvideo.mp4`

Comment: Works here on Win 7. Do you get an error msg?

Comment: If you get an error with ffmpeg, you don't probably have it. Download the exe and cooy to your project folder.